# Why am I getting 403 Forbidden when I enter a url directly but not when I click the link?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, http-status-code-403, httpforbiddenhandler

When I enter the URL of a page on my site directly into my address bar, I get a 403 Forbidden error, yet when I post the link on a forum etc and click it from there, I am able to access the site fine.

Comment: My guess would be something to do with the `HTTP_REFERER` header, which will be absent if you type the URL, but (probably) present if you click a link. But, there's nothing here to attempt a diagnosis with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being shown the url, or being able to see the configuration, I'd say the most likely reason is that your apache settings are denying access based on the referrer.

Comment: How can I change this?

Comment: It may not even be the reason... but what you need to look at is your .htaccess, and maybe your apache config file (something like /etc/apache2/httpd.conf). Or show me the url, and I'll see if this even is a possible reason.

Comment: This is just plain forbidden. I've tried with different referrers, and I've tried putting a link to that page in another page and clicking it in a browser. I always get a 403. I don't know how you can get it to work by posting the link to a forum.